# Конкатенация элементов многомерного массива php

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулась с проблемой... Помогите пожалуйста решить.

Ситуация такая
Есть отдельная таблица (momental) в ней значения id товаров, кол-во, цена, валюта и т. д
Есть 2 массива городов, а могут быть и 10, мне нужно все перебрать и соединить все momental_city
Вывод из БД

Код вывода:
$all = getAll("SELECT * FROM uni_momental WHERE momental_tovar_id= { $array_data["tovar"]['ads_id'] } ");
print_r($all);

Изначально массив заносила в JSON. Что бы легче было работать

Задача нужно сложить эти массивы в один большой массив этих значений
Мне в конце нужен такой результат:
["1133","1134","1142","1143","1144"]
Конкатенация многомерного массива php это где то близко, но не совсем помогла...

Для управления массивом momental_city (добавить/удаленить/обновить) в таблице MySQL
Скриншот прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: если momental_city это у вас обычный пхп массив, то `array_merge(...array_column($data, 'mometal_city'))`

Comment: если там json массив строкой. то еще добавить `array_map/json_encod` примерно в виде `array_merge(...array_map('json_encode', array_column($data, 'momental_city')))`

Comment: да и вообще, стоит задуматься, зачем хранить данные в БД, которые вам нужны в выборках в виде сериализованных строк.

Comment: Потому что 1200 городов и могут несколько тысяч товаров
Будет хотя бы 1000 товаров и для каждого товара может быть разные регионы и получается если 1000 товаров, то в этой таблице будет 1200000 записей
А если будет, 10к-50к товаров то гм)
А тут выбрал быстро товар и распаковал массив городов и все

Comment: Изначально массив заносила в JSON. Что бы легче было работать

Comment: А как найти товары по городу? Выбрать все и распаковывать каждый?

Comment: Да тоже самое, выбрать все записи от каждого товара, и все в 1 массив обьединить и найти id этого города в массиве

Comment: Ясно, вместо того чтобы хранить 12М записей и быстренько в них искать по индексу, лучше тянуть тысячу записей и по ним всем ходить.